# uuid4 regex в Django urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите, как я могу принять в `urls` `uuid`?

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12})/$', UserDetails.as_view(), name = 'users_detail'),

]
```

Так, но не получается.

Comment: да принимал бы вайлдкардом. то что там user_id должен быть и так понятно из начала урла. а спасаться таким образом от перебора урлов не вижу смысла. все равно нужна проверка на валидность

Answer (score 0):

`(?P<user_id>[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12})`

Или можно попробовать просто `(?P<user_id>[0-9a-f-]+)`